# Moebius transformations: Find linear transformation function T(z)=az +b/cz+d.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I am struggling with part c and d. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(c)$ Compose the LFT from $(a)$ with the inverse of the one in $(b)$.  The inverse is given by $f^{-1}(w)=\frac{dw-b}{-cw+a}$.  Or, if you like, compute it directly.

$(d)$  Use the fact that generalized circles go to generalized circles.  See what happens to $1,i,-1$, namely,  the circle determined by them ($\mid z\mid=1$) goes to the line through $\infty,i,2$.  Now use a test point to see which half plane the inside/outside of the circle goes to.

So, let's try $(c)$ directly.   $T(1)=\frac{a+b}{c+d}=\infty $.  So $c=-d$.  $T(i)=\frac{ai+b}{ci-c}=i$.  So $-c-ic=ai+b$.  Next $T(-1)=\frac{-a+b}{2d}=2\implies b=a+4d\implies-c-ic=ai+a-4c\implies a(1+i)=c(3-i)\implies a=\frac{3-i}{1+i}c$.  So $T(z)=\frac{\frac{3-i}{1+i}cz+\frac{3-i}{1+i}c-4c}{cz-c}=\frac{(3-i)cz+(3-i)c-(1+i)4c}{(1+i)(cz-c)}=\frac{(3-i)z-1-5i}{(1+i)z-1-i}$.

Now to test which side of the line through $\infty, i,2$ the inside of the circle goes to, we use the origin.   $T(0)=\frac{-1-5i}{-1-i}=\frac{1+5i}{1+i}=\frac{(6+4i)}2=3+2i$.  This point lies above and to the right of the line. Therefore...

Comment: How would you go about the inverse method?

Comment: Find the inverse of $S(w)$ using the formula I gave.  Then   $S^{-1}\circ R$ is your map.

Comment: So once I find a,b,c in terms of d. I plug them into the inverse formula and that’s the LFT required?

Comment: And what would I do if the region in part d was say in terms of y and x instead of z eg. y> x+1

Comment: Also how does the point 3+2i lie above the line? If it was subbed in to satisfy the line wouldn’t that mean it lies on the line?

Comment: The line is $y=-\frac12 x+1$.  $(3,2)$ is above it.

Comment: Where does that line come from?

Comment: Through $\infty,i$ and $2$.  See $i$ is just $(0,1)$.  $2$ is $(2,0)$.  So it's the line through those two points.

Comment: Ah I see thanks